# How to select the most recent rows for several codes in my table?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I have a table with the next columns: ID (PK, AutoIncrement), Line, Line_Cod, Latitude, Longitude, Time (Timestamp Auto).

Every row contains the coordinates of a certain line (bus number) in a certain moment, but, we have different busses with the same line number, and we distinguish them by their Line Code (Line_Cod).

So, for example, we can have the next rows in our table:

[image: Table image]

What I want to select is the last position of every bus, identified by their Line number, but distinguishing their line_cod. In the example above, if I look for line 50, I would like to get the ids 1,3 and 6 (not the 2 because is the same bus than the 6, but is an older record).

I know how to select the most recent row for just a line:

```
SELECT LINE, LINE_COD, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 
CONVERT_TZ( TIME,  '+00:00',  '+07:00' ) AS  'TIME'
FROM LOCATION
WHERE LINE = 50
ORDER BY TIME DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

But this only would give me the most recent record of all, no matter the Line_COD...

I'm quite new in all the databases world, any help about how to achieve this would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this query, however, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT LINE, LINE_COD, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 
CONVERT_TZ( TIME,  '+00:00',  '+07:00' ) AS  'TIME'
FROM LOCATION
WHERE LINE = 50
ORDER BY TIME DESC) L GROUPBY L.LINE
LIMIT 1;
```

Basically you need to group the rows by the LINE to get rid of duplicates. However, you cannot groupby and orderby in a single query in MySQL, so you need to make a subquery to select and order the items by their time first, then you group that table by the LINE to get rid of duplicates.

Edit:

You can also try SELECT DISTINCT. However, the problem with that is that you cannot select multiple fields or else your results would not be unique, from what I remember when I faced a similar problem. However, maybe I missed something at the time.

To display all the rows of the result as opposed to the last one. Also, I just realized that you would like to distinguish by LINE_COD not LINE. So here is the final query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT LINE, LINE_COD, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 
CONVERT_TZ( TIME,  '+00:00',  '+07:00' ) AS  'TIME'
FROM LOCATION
WHERE LINE = 50
ORDER BY TIME DESC) L GROUPBY L.LINE_COD;
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I've tried your query but it keeps showing just the last entry, no matter the Line_COD. I really don't have any clue to solve this.. xD

Comment: The reason why is because the LIMIT 1. I assumed you just wanted the last entry because that was in your original query. Remove the LIMIT 1 and it should show all the results. See my Edit above.

Comment: Yeah, I tried also without the Limit 1, and I've tried now your edit as well (with GROUP BY separated btw). But is still showing just the row with the most recent time.

Comment: See my edits above. I just realized you would like to distinguish by line code as opposed to the line number. You only get one entry previously because we are grouping by LINE. since we are selecting rows at the same line, this effectively returns only a single row if its being grouped by LINE.

Comment: Ok, I got it solved adding L.LINE_COD to the group by, that I guess is what you were trying to write. Thank you very much, it's working now!!